# I have written a logic for deciding which user can change the owner of an Account record. Is there a way to generalize this for other objects?

Tags: apex, trigger, ownership, business-logic

The logic is as follows:

```
public static void changeOwner(Map<Id, Account> newAccs, Map<Id, Account> oldAccs) {
        Map<Id, Id> objOwnerMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
        for(Account acc : newAccs.values()) {
            if(acc.OwnerId != oldAccs.get(acc.Id).OwnerId) {
                objOwnerMap.put(acc.Id, oldAccs.get(acc.Id).OwnerId);
                needCheck = true;
            }
        }

        if(needCheck) {
            oldOwnerMap = new Map<Id, User>([SELECT id, UserRoleId, UserRole.ParentRoleId 
                                             FROM User WHERE id IN: objOwnerMap.values()]);
            
            for(Account acc : newAccs.values()) {
                Id oldOwnerId = objOwnerMap.get(acc.Id);
                if((UserInfo.getUserRoleId() != oldOwnerMap.get(oldOwnerId).UserRoleId) && (UserInfo.getUserRoleId() != oldOwnerMap.get(oldOwnerId).UserRole.ParentRoleId)) {
                    acc.addError(System.Label.change_owner_error);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I have to use this logic for multiple objects like `Contact`, `Opportunity` etc. Is there a way I can generalize this? I tried using `sObject`, obviously it says `Variable does not exist: OwnerId`.

Comment: when using generic the SObject class, you need to fetch fields using `.get(<fieldname>)` and set fields using `.put(<filedname>, <value>)`. That aside, I think this may be better off as a validation rule on your target objects. Yes, you'd be largely duplicating validation rules, but avoiding queries may be worth it. Is there a reason why this needs to be done in Apex?

Comment: If you look at penultimate code line,  in validation rule how can I get the owner's role to do this check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the sObject#get method:

```
if(acc.get('OwnerId') != oldAccs.get(acc.Id).get('OwnerId')) {
```

You'll need to use sObject everywhere, of course, but the sObject#get method is how you get fields generically.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same logic to be applied to multiple objects, using [sObject](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46580/how-to-use-sobject-in-trigger) is the correct approach. However, you cannot directly reference the ownerId field. It gives a [null value](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12583/sobject-ownerid-returns-null) and that is expected.

My recommendation is to use the following [dynamic solution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_id.htm)

```
public class MyDynamicSolution {
@future
public static void updateOwner(List<ID> objIds, ID newOwnerId) {
    // Validate input
    System.assert(objIds != null);
    System.assert(objIds.size() > 0);
    System.assert(newOwnerId != null);
    
    // Get the sObject token from the first ID
    // (the List contains IDs of sObjects of the same type).
    Schema.SObjectType token = objIds[0].getSObjectType();
    
    // Using the token, do a describe 
    // and construct a query dynamically. 
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult dr = token.getDescribe();
    String queryString = 'SELECT ownerId FROM ' + dr.getName() + 
        ' WHERE ';
    for(ID objId : objIds) {
        queryString += 'Id=\'' + objId + '\' OR ';
    }    
    // Remove the last ' OR'
    queryString = queryString.subString(0, queryString.length() - 4);

    sObject[] objDBList = Database.query(queryString);
    System.assert(objDBList.size() > 0);
    
    // Update the owner ID on the sObjects
    for(Integer i=0;i<objDBList.size();i++) {
        objDBList[i].put('ownerId', newOwnerId);
    }        
    Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.update(objDBList, false);
    for(Database.SaveResult sr : srList) {
        if (sr.isSuccess()) {
            System.debug('Updated owner ID successfully for ' + 
                dr.getName() + ' ID ' + sr.getId());
        }
        else {
            System.debug('Updating ' + dr.getName() + ' returned the following errors.');
            for(Database.Error e : sr.getErrors()) {
                System.debug(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There's absolutely no need to use `for(ID objId : objIds) {
        queryString += 'Id=\'' + objId + '\' OR ';
    }` to populate the query, just use `... WHERE Id IN :objIds`.

Comment: Also, why re-query objects to get the owner when the owner is simply being overwritten? You don't need to query data using SOQL that you are going to simply overwrite and then store to the DB via DML.